# Manipulation of a multiple cross product expression using skew symmetric matrices

Tags: cross-product, skew-symmetric-matrices

In the derivation of equation (8.23) in the book "Modern Robotics: Mechanics, Planning, and Control" there are some manipulations of the term for the moment contribution of the centripetal acceleration which are unclear to me. The main manipulation steps are given as follows where I am particularly confused about the last step:

\begin{align}
[r_i][\omega_b]^2r_i &= [r_i][\omega_b][\omega_b]r_i \\\\
&= -[r_i][\omega_b][r_i]\omega_b \\\\
&= -[r_i]^T[\omega_b]^T[r_i]\omega_b \\\\
&= -[\omega_b][r_i]^2\omega_b
\end{align}

The notation $[a]$ is the skew symmetric matrix of a vector $a$ used for cross products whereby $a\times b=[a]b$. The given properties for these manipulations are $[a] = -[a]^T$, $[a]b = -[b]a$, and $[a][b] = ([b][a])^T$.

I know that the cross product is not associative in general ($(a\times b)\times c \neq a\times (b\times c)$) and that the operations should be evaluated from right to left. However it seems like the transpose operations cause order of evaluation to reverse. More specifically my attempted understanding is as follows:

\begin{align}
-[r_i]([\omega_b]([r_i]\omega_b)) &= -([r_i]^T[\omega_b]^T)([r_i]\omega_b) \\\\
&= ([\omega_b]^T[r_i]^T)([r_i]\omega_b) \\\\
&= [\omega_b]([r_i]([r_i]\omega_b)) \\\\
&= [\omega_b]([r_i]^2\omega_b)
\end{align}

But the sign isn't correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You evaluate -as you say- $[r_i][\omega_b][\omega_b]r_i$ from right to left. So in your attempt to understand it why did you put that minus sign in front?

Comment: $−[r_i]([\omega_b]([r_i]\omega_b))$ is starting from the second line from the steps given in the book. Also in my original attempt in the question I got confused thinking that $[r_i]^T[\omega_b]^T=-[\omega_b]^T[r_i]^T$ but I can't do this because $[\omega]$ isn't a vector. I posted a solution clearing this up.

Comment: Ok. Point taken. I am throwing only quick thoughts at you. Next one: I think when you go to from your first line to your second line you think that there is a sign change when you switch the order of $[r_i]^T$ and $[\omega_b]^T$ but I don't think that is the case. The sign change occurs only in the interaction of a matrix with a vector. The rule you should apply there is $[a][b]=([b][a])^\top\,.$

Comment: All good, I appreciate you taking a look. Okay I can't see how to apply $[a][b]=([b][a])^T$ though. I can see $[r_i]^T[\omega_b]^T=([\omega_b][r_i])^T$ but then how does this equal $[\omega_b][r_i]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Even though the cross product is not associative, matrix multiplication is and $[a]$ is a matrix. The property $[a]b=-[b]a$ requires $b$ be a vector so $[a][b]\neq -[b][c]$ but $[a]([b]c)=-([b][c])a$. Keeping these in mind and using slightly different manipulations than the book I get the following:
\begin{align}
[r_i][\omega_b][\omega_b]r_i &= [r_i]\big([\omega_b]([\omega_b]r_i)\big) \\\\
&= -[r_i]\big(([\omega_b][r_i])\omega_b\big) \\\\
&= \big(([\omega_b][r_i])[\omega_b]\big)r_i \\\\
&= [\omega_b][r_i]\big([\omega_b]r_i\big) \\\\
&= -[\omega_b][r_i]\big([r_i]\omega_b\big) \\\\
&= -[\omega_b]\big([r_i][r_i]\big)\omega_b \\\\
&= -[\omega_b][r_i]^2\omega_b
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Consider the relation
$[\mathbf{a} \times][\mathbf{b} \times]+
\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T =
[\mathbf{b} \times][\mathbf{a} \times]+
\mathbf{b}\mathbf{a}^T
$

This gives for any vector $\mathbf{c}$ the relation
$$
[\mathbf{r}_i \times][\mathbf{w}_b \times]
\mathbf{c}+
\mathbf{r}_i \mathbf{w}_b^T \mathbf{c}
=
[\mathbf{w}_b \times][\mathbf{r}_i \times]
\mathbf{c}+
\mathbf{w}_b \mathbf{r}_i^T \mathbf{c}
 \tag{1}
$$

Now using the particular vector
$$
\mathbf{c}
=[\mathbf{w}_b \times] \mathbf{r}_i
=-[\mathbf{r}_i \times] \mathbf{w}_b
$$
the scalar products $\mathbf{r}_i^T \mathbf{c}$ and
$\mathbf{w}_b^T \mathbf{c}$ are null by construction.

Thus (1) simplifies to
$$
[\mathbf{r}_i \times][\mathbf{w}_b \times]
\mathbf{c}
=
[\mathbf{w}_b \times][\mathbf{r}_i \times]
\mathbf{c}
$$ which is the desired relation.

Comment: What's a good reference for the original relation? At first I wasn't sure why the those scalar products are null but then I realized that c is perpendicular to them.

Comment: Although this solution is more elegant I am going to accept my answer as it more similar to the derivation in the book.